# Quarkus : Config root [HibernateOrmRuntimeConfig] with config phase [RUN_TIME] not initialized yet

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

I cannot run my quarkus due to HibernateOrmRuntimeConfig initialisation.

I am new to Quarkus. I try to build an application with Hibernate reactive with Panache. I have some entities (some inherit from PanacheEntity, and some inherit from PanacheEntityBase because the id is not Long).
I put that entities in the package entities (inside the main package).

My dependencies are :

```
quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache
quarkus-reactive-mysql-client
quarkus-resteasy-reactive
quarkus-arc
quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson
quarkus-junit5
rest-assured
```

I don't know why when I run the project with `quarkus dev` I got this error :

```
[io.qua.arc.impl] (Quarkus Main Thread) An error occurred during delivery of the @BeforeDestroyed(ApplicationScoped.class) event: javax.enterprise.inject.: Config root [io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRuntimeConfig] with config phase [RUN_TIME] not initialized yet.
```

My application.properties :

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=vertx-reactive:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.password=
quarkus.datasource.reactive.name=my_db
```

Any solution to resolve this issue and to understand its causes ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance you can share your application on GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

I know where I made the mistake. It was a class having a constructor with only one field, without having another with no args.

I added a no args constructor and it works well now!